# Non-working cache.manifest on iPad and Safari Desktop

Tags: ipad, html, caching, safari, mime-types

I'm trying to create an offline version of a test web app.
This far it had been working perfectly on Chrome and Firefox where I do most of my tests. Meaning I can go to the page, the console is all good, and then when I unplug my ethernet cable (I'm hardcore like that) I can see still all of my page content in browser and in chrome://appcache-internals

Problems arise when I try to test it on the iPad, I go to my webpage, but then when going into Airplane mode it refuses to access the page saying I need an internet connection. So I decided to test on Safari (mac) which is the closest I have, and I do see an error in the console on the cache.manifest mime-type : `Application Cache manifest had an incorrect MIME type: text/plain.`

Problem is, I do have a .htaccess and it does specify `AddType text/cache-manifest appcache manifest`, but no. Even when I use a web sniffer on my cache.manifest file it comes out as text/plain, which I think might be the reason it's not getting read on the iPad/Safari.

Anyone can help me on this thing ? I'm completely stuck right now.

Comment: Link to the said page : http://stappler.fr/webapp/index.html

Comment: Have you checked with your hosting provider that their Appache config allows you to override content types in `.htaccess`?

Comment: I'm thinking this may be it. I'm using .htaccess a lot but I've never tried to modify content types. My code is working fine on another hosting so I guess it is indeed a matter of hosting Apache config.

Answer (score 2):

add to your manifest file NETWORK and FALLBACK blocks so it will look like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Version 1.0

NETWORK:
*

CACHE:
index.html

FALLBACK:
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Private Browsing enabled in Safari on your iPad:

Settings -> Safari -> Private Browsing

If it is enabled, disable it. When Private Browsing is enabled all cookies and other caching is disabled.

I had a similar problem. My app worked fine with internet disconnected both on Safari and Firefox running on the iMac and even on the iPhone in airplane mode. But when I tried to load it on the iPad in Airplane mode it just wouldn't work. When I turned off Private Browsing it worked! Still got the notice about turning off Aerplane Mode though. But it was possible to browse the App.